# .Net core vs framework - adding wcf service

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, wcf, soap

I'm working on a .net framework project I have added to it a WCF service.
The service is of a soap type.

Now I'm trying to add the same WCF service to a .net core 6 project.

Unfortunately, at the .net core project, the web service generates only part of the client functions of the service.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to post here the web service for security reasons.

I'm not able to figure out the difference between the 2 projects that cause the web service to generate only part of the client functions.

When I'm trying to test the WCF service through soap UI it works perfectly.

NOTE: the web service contains resources that are NOT accessible from my IP.

Does anyone have any idea on how can i fix it ?

Comment: check this https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

Comment: Are you using `CoreWCF`? Please check [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/).